# Por que declarar o ID do timeout fora do callback da função debounce?

Tags: javascript, funções, callback

Esta é uma função que imprime no console o que eu digito no input.

Eu gostaria de entender o porquê de que, quando eu declaro o ID do `setTimeout` (nesse caso chamada `time`) fora da função, ela funciona como uma função debouncer, mas, se eu declaro dentro da função, ela continua mandando várias requisições e não funciona?

Script que funciona:

```
let time
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(time)
    time = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }, 1500) 
})
```

Script que não funciona:

```
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(time)
    let time = setTimeout(() => {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }, 1500) 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perceba que você, antes de criar um novo *timeout* (utilizando o `setTimeout`), deve *remover* o *timeout* anterior usando a função `clearTimeout`.

Vejamos o exemplo de código que *não* funciona:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  clearTimeout(time);
  let time = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Perceba que, nesse código, existem dois problemas:

- A única referência para o `id` do *timeout* (que no seu código chama-se `time`) está dentro da função de *callback*. Como o *callback* é executado para cada evento `keyup`, você sempre criará um novo *timeout* e, uma vez que o *callback* "termine", você não terá mais referência ao ID dele, já que se perdeu dentro do escopo da função que, nesse momento, já deixara de ser executada.
- O `clearTimeout` vem antes da declaração de `time` em si. Isso causa um erro, uma vez que, como `time` é criado a cada evento, ele ainda não foi criado quando `clearTimeout` tenta acessá-lo. Por conta disso, você terá um `ReferenceError`.

Desse modo, há de se *manter* o ID do **último** *timeout* criado para que o próximo *event handler* possa limpá-lo. Uma forma de fazer isso é manter a variável `time` **fora** do *callback* (como faz o seu código que funciona):

```
let time; // <--- Note que a variável é externa ao callback.
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  clearTimeout(time);
  time = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }, 1500);
});
```

Agora, como declaramos `time` **fora** do *callback*, a referência ao ID do último *timeout* executado não mais será perdida. Como `time` está, também, declarado antes do `clearTimeout` (que, no seu código, faz uso do nome `time`), não haverá mais também `ReferenceError`.

Exemplo funcional:

```js
let time; // <--- Note que a variável é externa ao callback.
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
  clearTimeout(time);
  time = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }, 1500);
});
```

```html
<input type="text" />
```

Comment: Show show! Ficou bem claro, muito obrigado Luiz!